# What happens to a mass if you apply an acceleration to it, apply a second (equal) acceleration to the accelerating mass, etc?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, spring, rocket-science

Suppose we have a mass that is being accelerated in empty space. Say by pulling on it by an accelerating rocket. This rocket is non-rigidly (say by a spring with spring constant $k$ and length $l$ when not stretched) connected to another rocket which gives the accelerating system behind it an acceleration.

The acceleration is the same for each rocket, as well as the springs connecting them. So the acceleration is accelerated. A third rocket (connected in the same way to the second) gives the accelerated acceleration system behind it an acceleration again. And so on. The row contains a finite amount of rockets and the rockets and connections are to be considered massless.

What will be the acceleration in this case? For certain, it's not the sum of all accelerations of the rockets. This would, obviously, be the case if all rockets were connected to the mass directly.

But what *will* the acceleration of $m$ be? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Does this not just depend on the acceleration of the rocket with the largest acceleration?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are confused about the difference between force and acceleration. Just maybe...

Comment: @BillN How do you mean? I could ask the same question in the context of the force exerted on the mass, by all the forces the rockets exert on each other.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that not "all rockets are connected to the mass". But there is absolutely no distinction between every rocket connected directly to the mass, and one long series of rockets connected to one another with only one attached directly to the mass - so long as the connections are rigid, each case is a single body that has identical mass and thrust.

Comment: Then let's assume the connections are non-rigid. The first force makes the mass accelerate. The second force causes the accelerating system to accelerate. The third force will accelerate accelerated acceleration, etc.

Comment: Do you want mathematical explanations?

Comment: Your edit makes the most upvoted ans irrelevant 

Comment: Why do you think that? I got forces involved now.

Comment: Your edit made the connections non rigid

Comment: Is it  that you  just wanted to hear  "math_error_too_many_unknowns!" ?

Comment: After your edit to your question it no longer makes sense. I will delete my pre edit answer. Good luck

Comment: @AdrianHoward Thanks! Good luck to you too!

Comment: @Protein I think you don't understand the problem at all!

Comment: @Protein Hey multi amino acid!. Don't be so suspicious (or should I say paranoid?)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the connections are rigid, all $n$ rockets and the mass must have the same acceleration.

If the connections are not rigid, the problem does not seem to be well-defined as there are too many unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

Are you avoiding the concept of force and vectors purposely?? If not here's the solution.

Analysing the forces makes the problem really simple.

Assume each rocket generates a thrust of $\mathrm{t}$ newtons . The acceleration($\vec{a}$)of mass $\mathrm{m}$ is simply the vector sum of forces divided by $\mathrm{m}$

.$$\vec{a}=\frac{\vec{f_{net}}}{\mathrm{m}}$$

No matter how the rockets are connected -directly or indirectly the apply the same force and if the orientation of rockets is same and connections are rigid in both of your cases the acceleration of mass would be same in both.

If the object is extend the you have to look at the acceleration of centre of mass.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. As I wrote in my question, this would be the case if all rockets would be not connected to each other, but only to the mass. Suppose there is only one rocket that exerts a force on the mass. Piece of cake. To this accelerating system, we apply a second force by means of a rocket tied only to the first one. This means the acceleration is accelerated by this force. The unit for accelerated acceleration is $\frac{m^2}{{sec}^4}$.

Comment: This means your formula doesn't apply. When the third rocket is connected to the second, exerting a force to the system behind it we have an accelerated acceleration of the acceleration. Unit: $\frac{m^3}{{sec}^6}$. Etcetera. So only with one rocket, your answer is correct but not in the case with two or more.